# Sort one list into any number of lists evenly in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, random

I have a list of objects here:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    list.add(x);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

As well as a list of other lists that I want the items of `list` to be sorted into evenly.

```
List<List<Object>> evenLists = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    evenLists.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
}
```

eg. 25 in each list in `evenLists` but if there are 5 lists in `evenLists` then 20 each
I have this so far, but it only works with 2 defined lists sorting them 50/50

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
double chance = 0.5D;
for(Object obj:list) {
    if(list1.size() < (list.size() * chance1)) {
        list1.add(obj);
    } else if(list2.size() < list.size() * chance2) {
        list2.add(obj);
    } else {
        list1.add(obj);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an approach I can take to reach this?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail? The question is confusing.

Comment: This question seems far too trivial and localised for this site.  However, it's quite clear what's being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method like this, then you can choose how many lists to partition into

```
public List<List<Object>> partionList( List<Object> yourList, int numPartitions)
{
   List<List<Object>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
   for(int i = 0; i < numPartitions; i++)
       resultList.add(new ArrayList<Object>());

   int counter = 0;
   for(Object o:yourList)
   {
       resultList.get(counter % numPartitions).add(o);           
       counter++;
   }
   return resultList
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think to just use modulus, worked great!

Answer (score 1):

- [partition](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) from [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)?
- [partition](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/)?

Comment: Neither of those libraries partition evenly.   They both say that the lists will be the same size except the last which may be smaller.  For example partition `[123456789]` into lists of size no more than 4 would yield `[1234],[5678],[9]` instead of `[123],[456],[789]`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller If you pick a list size to partition into that's unavoidable. The parameter is an absolute sub-list size, not a maximum sub-list size.

Comment: I'm looking for one where the resulting partitions are all similarly sized.  At most they should be off by one.   For example `[1234567890]` into lists of 4 would yield `[1234],[567],[890]` instead of `[1234],[5678],[90]`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Okay, cool. Seems like that's a simple math problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like this:

```
int i=0;
for (Object obj:list) {
   EvenLists.get(i % evenLists.size()).add(obj);
   i++;
}
```